# Talend Open Studio : SQL Server 2017 Connection issue

Tags: sql-server, talend

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2017 in Talend Open Studio Designer but getting below error while connecting:

Error:

[image]

Talend connection:

[image]

I am able to connect to SQL Server using same credentials:

[image]

Comment: try using instance=SQLEXPRESS in the additional parameters

Comment: Are you using the right JDBC provider in your tMSSql componant(s)?

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully connected to SQL Server 2008 and 2012 R2 with no problems but when work decided I needed a new machine and our environments were upgraded to 2017 I had to updated my tools.

After installing SQL Server 2017 and going through the normal set up procedures I still was unable to connect. Here are the reference materials I fought through but if you want to jump to the solution that worked to me it is marked below.

First I followed the instructions here for configuring the SQL Server environment:

[Talend SQL Server Instructions](https://help.talend.com/reader/5egGyP0F8KSW1AUuEl4MBg/ZK9sBAtvuqH8OA9kuxlJ5g) - There are some scripting steps there that I did run, but I'm not convinced actually helped anything so in the interest of completeness I did want to include this.

[Additional Considerations](https://help.talend.com/reader/AE4vCooS6gkcjmMtImcQDw/KLVOGvlkBe0c6a4HT9zl~g) - I actually used the Microsoft option instead of what is indicated by this document and it gave me far better error messages

**SOLUTION STARTS HERE**

Enable/Configure TCP/IP on SQL Server Configuration Manager

- Insure TCP/IP is enabled on the instance you are using
- Right click on TCP/IP and select properties
- Select the IP Address Tab scroll to the bottom "IPALL" and set TCP
  Dynamic Ports = 1433
- Restart the Services

[image]

Next I set Talend using the following parameters:

- Changed DB Version to Microsoft (you may be prompted to update the
  .jar file for this)
- Server: MyServer
- Port: 1433
- Database: myDB
- Additional Parameters: instance=NamedInstance

[image]

Here is what SSMS Show for reference:

[image]

I hope this gets you there.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I searched for hours but did not set the TCPIP port, this fixed it for me! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a problem with encryption. Try:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

additional jdbc parameters

"useSSL=false"